# Cms Page 404 after checkout/cart page

Tags: cms, 404-page

I have an issue with my magento store.

Only when I'm on the shopping cart page (checkout/cart) and I want to navigate to a CMS page a 404 error appears and the link is (checkout/cart/cms-page-name).

Someone can help me to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you given navigation link statically

If you use static link must use

```
<a href="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(); ?>cms-page-identifier">cms-page-name</a>
```